# Programmatically create scroll view in android studio with buttons.!

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to make an app with this look [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQQ9H.jpg)

but programmatically such that I can change the number of shown boxes in runtime.
I have tried the following, but no success-
1)MainActivity.java

```
package com.bigx.dynamictesting;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_relative);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
 for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int)(300 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, (int)(20 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
        textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        textView.setText("TextView" + i);
        linearLayout.addView(textView);

        Button buttonA = new Button(this);
        Button buttonB = new Button(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsA = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)(60 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density),(int)(60 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
        layoutParamsA.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, textView.getId());
        layoutParamsA.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END, textView.getId());


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsB = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)(60 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density),(int)(60 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
        layoutParamsA.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, textView.getId());
        layoutParamsA.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START, textView.getId());

        buttonA.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsA);
        buttonA.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        linearLayout.addView(buttonA);

        buttonB.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsB);
        buttonB.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        linearLayout.addView(buttonB);
    }
    relativeLayout.addView(linearLayout);
}
```

2) activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="0dp"
android:fillViewport="false"
android:background="@color/colorAccent">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.bigx.dynamictesting">

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Which yields this result-[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htmrA.jpg)

Kindly suggest me how to achieve my objective.
Thank you.
P.S.-Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I think recycler view is good choice for you.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/